# Supremum of the function $f(x,y,z,u)=\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)z(1-u)}{1-(1-xy)z}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, supremum-and-infimum

Consider a function $$f(x,y,z,u)=\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)z(1-u)}{1-(1-xy)z} $$ where $x,y,z,u\in (0,1)$

> I need the supremum of $f(x,y,z,u)$ for $x,y,z,u\in (0,1)$

We have $1-(1-xy)z=1-z+xyz$

Now since $x,y,z\in(0,1)$, so we have $1-z>0$ and by AM-GM inequality
$$1-(1-xy)z=1-z+xyz\geq 2\sqrt{(1-z)xyz}$$
So we have $$f(x,y,z,u)\leq \frac{1}{2} \frac{\sqrt{x}(1-x)\sqrt{y}(1-y)z(1-u)}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}} $$
Now if $G(x)=\sqrt{x}(1-x)$ and we put $t=\sqrt{x}$ then the supremum of $G(x)=t(1-t^2)$ occurs when $1-3t^3=0$ so at $t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ so we have $$f(x,y,z,u)<\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1-\frac{1}{3})\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1-\frac{1}{3})z(1-u)}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}) $$
So $$f(x,y,z,u)<\frac{2}{27}\frac{z(1-u)}{\sqrt{z(1-z)}}$$
Please solve this question.

Comment: Note that $f$ is strictly decreasing in $u$, so the supremum must have $u = 0$.

Comment: Symmetric in $x$ and $y$ so let $y=x$.

Comment: @BobDobbs So what will be the supremum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing the function as
$$
f(x,y,z,u) = \frac{xyz}{1-z+xyz}(1-x)(1-y)(1-u),
$$
we have a product of four terms all strictly less than $1$. Therefore $f(x,y,z,u) < 1$ for all $x,y,z,u\in(0,1)$.

To show that $1$ is the supremum, we need to show we can get arbitrarily close to it. The product form above suggests making $x, y, u$ close to $0$ and $z$ close to $1$. So we consider
$$
f(x,y,1-w,u) = \frac{(1-x)(1-y)(1-u)}{1 + \frac{w}{xy(1-w)}} > 1 - \left[x+y+u+\frac{w}{xy(1-w)}\right]
$$
The term in brackets can be made arbitrarily small through suitable choice of $x,y,u,w\in (0,1)$, so $1$ is indeed the supremum.

Comment: @Max Changed the answer to have a more valid derivation.

Comment: So we have product of four terms all striclty less than $1$. But there is also a term $\frac{1}{1-z+xyz}$. This term is not less than $1$. So how do we have $f(x,y,z,u) < 1$ for all $x,y,z,u\in(0,1)$?

Comment: $xyz  < 1 - z + xyz$, so the fraction is smaller than 1.

Comment: +1. I am accepting your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here

$$
f(x,y,z,u)=\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)z(1-u)}{1-(1-xy)z} = g(x,y,z)(1-u)
$$

now as $g(x,y,z)\ge 0$ we have that $u=0$. Considering now $\epsilon> 0$,  $0\lt z+\epsilon\lt 1$ we have

$$
g(x,y,z+\epsilon) =\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)z}{1-(1-xy)(z+\epsilon)}+\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)\epsilon}{1-(1-xy)(z+\epsilon)}\gt \frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)z}{1-(1-xy)z}
$$

because

$$
\frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)z}{1-(1-xy)(z+\epsilon)}\gt \frac{x(1-x)y(1-y)z}{1-(1-xy)z}
$$

so the supremum is attained at

$$
\sup f(x,y,z,u) = \lim_{\cases{x(z)\to 0\\ y(z)\to 0\\ z\to 1}}f(x,y,z,0)=1
$$

NOTE

To determine a possible path $x(z),y(z)$ we follow with the problem

$$
\max_{s}u(s,z) = \frac{s^2(1-s)^2z}{1-(1-s^2)z},\ \ \ (\text{here}\ \ s=x=y)
$$

now from $u'(s,z) = 0$ and solving a cubic we got a real root as

$$
s(z) = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2} \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{(1-z)^2 z^3 (32-5 z)}+9 (1-z) z^2\right)^{2/3}-4 \sqrt[3]{3} (1-z) z}{6^{2/3} z
   \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{(1-z)^2 z^3 (32-5 z)}+9 (1-z) z^2}}
$$

Follows a plot for $s(z), \ 0 < z < 1$

[image]

and also for $u(s(z),z), \  \ 0 < z < 1$

[image]

Comment: +1 for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Due to symmetry we can take $x=y$ (Still trying to find a better justification) and as eyeballfrog commented $u\rightarrow 0$ gives supremum. Hence, we consider the function $f(x,z)=\frac{x^2(1-x)^2z}{1-(1-x^2)z}$ on $D=(0,1)×(0,1)$. Assume that $f(x,z)>1$. Then,$z>\frac{1}{1-x^2(1-(1-x)^2)}>1$ when $0<x<1$. Therefore, $\sup_D f(x,z)=1$, achived by $x\rightarrow 0$, $z\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Previous version of this question was deleted and only today I found this one. May be this is not complete answer, but let me bring here some calculation in hope, they will be useful:
First derivatives are:
$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial \:}{\partial \:x}\left(\dfrac{x\left(1-x\right)y\left(1-y\right)z\left(1-u\right)}{1-\left(1-xy\right)z}\right)=\dfrac{yz\left(-x^2yz+2xz-2x-z+1\right)\left(1-y\right)\left(1-u\right)}{\left(1-z\left(1-xy\right)\right)^2}\\
\dfrac{\partial \:}{\partial \:y}\left(\dfrac{x\left(1-x\right)y\left(1-y\right)z\left(1-u\right)}{1-\left(1-xy\right)z}\right)=\dfrac{xz\left(-xy^2z+2yz-2y-z+1\right)\left(1-x\right)\left(1-u\right)}{\left(1-z\left(1-xy\right)\right)^2}\\
\dfrac{\partial \:}{\partial \:z}\left(\dfrac{x\left(1-x\right)y\left(1-y\right)z\left(1-u\right)}{1-\left(1-xy\right)z}\right)=\dfrac{xy\left(1-x\right)\left(1-y\right)\left(1-u\right)}{\left(1-z\left(1-xy\right)\right)^2}\\
\dfrac{\partial \:}{\partial \:u}\left(\dfrac{x\left(1-x\right)y\left(1-y\right)z\left(1-u\right)}{1-\left(1-xy\right)z}\right)=-\dfrac{xyz\left(1-x\right)\left(1-y\right)}{1-z\left(1-xy\right)}\\
\end{cases}$$
From last two lines is obvious, that extremum cannot be inside $(0,1)^4$.

Calculating [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) (for saving space I am not including explicit formulas for second derivatives)
$$\begin{vmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial y \partial x}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial z \partial x}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial u \partial x}f\\ 
    \dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x \partial y}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{ \partial y^2}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{ \partial z \partial y}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{ \partial u \partial y}f\\
    \dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x \partial z}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{ \partial y \partial z}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{ \partial^2 z }f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{ \partial u \partial z }f\\
    \dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x \partial u}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{ \partial y \partial u}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{ \partial z \partial u}f & \dfrac{\partial^2 }{ \partial^2 u  }f
\end{vmatrix}_{\Big|_{(1,1,z,u)}}=\begin{vmatrix}
    0 & z(1-u) & 0 & 0\\ 
    z(1-u) & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

shows, that [Second partial derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test) is not applicable in points $(1,1,z,u)$. I'll try more deep methods and bring them in nearest future.

Comment: Somebody have no patience, but I remember promises and it will be shame for that somebody.